# External display color changes when MacBook lid is closed

Tags: macos, display, closed-clamshell

I have no idea how, as the color profile remains the same, but whenever I close the lid on my MacBook, the external monitor changes to a blue tint.

I've tried changing the monitor's settings, as well as ensuring the right color profile is on.

Comment: Go to System Preferences app → Displays → Display and check if you have True Tone enabled. Try toggling it and see if affects the setting.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: Turning off "True Tone" on the mac display fixed my problem. Now the external display has the same color whether or not the MacBook display lid is closed

Comment: turn on HDR if it is supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you update to macOS 10.15.4 it may now detect that you have a HDR screen, and makes your external screen colors look weird.**

To fix this:

- Go to Display settings
- Uncheck "High Dynamic Range" for your external display
- Everything should be back to normal.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. My external monitor doesn't support HDR, so PaulVO's method didn't work for me.

As Nimesh suggested, I unchecked the "True Tone" for my Mac retina display. I immediately saw my Mac display had the same blue tint. Then I was able to calibrate both the color of my Retina display and external monitor. Somewhere between D50 and D65 works best as qrius suggested.

Thank you all for the inputs!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, an options called "True Tone" was enabled. I have unchecked it and the monitor acted normally after then. I found the option in the Macbook's display settings not the external one, meaning it actually apply the same effect to the external monitor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have researched, there is no one button click way to fix it but you can do it through Calibration Assistant.

1. Go to Display Settings
2. If your monitor supports HDR, make sure it is unchecked.
3. Click on Color tab.
4. Click Calibrate and keep clicking continue until whitepoint setting screen, and then move the slider until you get your preferred tint level.

I kept it somewhere between D50 and D65 to give me the tint similar to when MacBook Lid was kept open.

Answer (score 0):

I love the True Tone features, so I choose to increase my LG monitor color temperature instead, that's inconvenient because each time I close the lid, I have to switch the color temp setting between 2 presets: 1 for lid open, 1 for lid close :((

It's too inconvenient, so finally I disabled the True Tone, and turn on Night Shift all day with a slightly warm setting :)) The downside is the color is not correct if Night Shift is turned on

There was a discussion here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254683389